# To what extent are microtubule-filaments present in astrocyte leaflets?

Tags: cell-biology, neuron, cytoskeleton

I have been trying to find information about whether microtubule filaments are present in the leaflets of astrocytes. A astrocyte can have quite varied morphology but many at least, have a star-like shape, with multiple branches, that become progressively branched into thinner processes. I found a suggested terminology for the progressively thinner branches here: [Diversity of astrocyte functions and phenotypes in neural circuits](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5258184/PMC5258184)
Soma --> Branches --> Branchlets --> Leaflets

The leaflets are really thin, maybe around 200 nm in width, and contact synapses at the "tripartite synapse".

What I'm curious about is whether there are microtubule filaments extended into these thinner leaflets. I know they are present in the branches and branchlets. But since MT filaments are around 25 nm in width I was thinking they were maybe too thin. I also read in a [A closer look at astrocyte morphology: Development, heterogeneity, and plasticity at astrocyte leaflets](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0959438822000447?casa_token=G0Kc7nXaUv4AAAAA:qDYGuHbW8Rfbh1SY1GwndMLbI_Lb2wJxPYLMpn0JoXBWUxKcua9rWetRZ_1aOOiFGRimSjmb5uQ) saying that "The peripheral, leaflet-like processes which comprise much of the astrocyte volume exclude these large filaments and instead rely on actin dynamics for their structure, much like neuronal spines" But when I read the referenced article I couldn't find the authors making any similar conclusion...so I don't know, I'm really curious about this, if anyone has any idea, intuition, or facts (though I'll welcome any hunch) that would be greatly appreciated!